# Problem starting MongoDB for the first time (MAC)

Tags: mongodb

I tried setting up MongoDB for the first time and I got this error - I recently changed my DNS so I'm not sure if it's related to that. Any ideas what this might mean?

I was following a tutorial on YouTube (Video Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIByvzueqHQ). I've seen other entries/issues similar to my one but I believe it might be different. People have said it may be ownership problems. I haven't seen one that says `Connection refused` - so I will change my DNS back and see if that does anything.

MongoDB shell version `v4.0.9`
connecting to:

```
mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb`
2019-07-30T16:14:05.184+1000 E QUERY  

   `[js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017`,
   connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to `127.0.0.1:27017` :: caused by ::
   Connection refused :

   `connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13@(connect):2:6 
   exception: connect failed`
```

I expected it to start MongoDB so I could give it a test run. This was the only error I saw.

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the mongodb service is not running on the mac.
To start it, try this:

```
brew services start mongodb
```